# shell exit code with code-block and pipe

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, exit-code

In a shell script I'm using a code-block with curly brackets to pipe all output to console and a log-file with tee.

```
#!/bin/bash

{
  echo "Foo bar"
  echo "foo bar on STDERR" >&2
  ERRL=66
  exit 99
} 2>&1 | tee log-file.log
```

(This is only a small demo script, the original is much more complex)

The problem is, that the line `exit 99` has no effect, the script ends with exit code 0. (This is the exit code of the tee command, I think)

I tried to add the line `exit $ERRL` at the end of the script, but it shows, that the variable $ERRL is empty outside the curly brackets.

What can I do, to end the script with an error code when something went wrong within the code-block -- without loosing the output to the log-file?

Comment: Check the bash PIPESTATUS array.  See http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html

Comment: Boo, hiss re: linking to the ABS -- it's rather notorious for being only sporadically maintained and, when not outright inaccurate, showcasing bad practices. Granted, that specific page isn't so bad (a little out-of-date, but nothing obviously outright wrong), but reviewing the ones immediately prior, section 9.2 is missing outright a number of bash 4.3 updates, and shows an _extremely_ error-prone way of identifying variable types when reliable ones are available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The least-intrusive way to redirect the output of your entire script is to do so once, up-front, without any blocking constructs involved:

```
exec > >(tee log-file.log) 2>&1 # redirect stdout and stderr to a pipe to tee

echo "Foo bar"
echo "foo bar on STDERR" >&2
ERRL=66
exit 99
```

Alternate options include using the `pipefail` setting...

```
set -o pipefail
{ ... } 2>&1 | tee log-file.log
```

...or explicitly pulling the exit status out after-the-fact:

```
{ ... } 2>&1 | tee log-file.log
exit "${PIPESTATUS[0]}"
```

...or just using a redirection that isn't a pipeline:

```
{ ... } > >(tee log-file.log) 2>&1
```

Comment: I choose the PIPESTATUS-solution for my script, because I just have to add one line.
But the next time I write something similar I'll choose the exec-solution.

Answer (score 0):

That is because the exit code is the one of the *last* command in a pipeline, unless you have `set -o pipefail` before the pipe. As [@jimmcnamara hinted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27947347/shell-exit-code-with-code-block-and-pipe/27948376#comment44291511_27947347), the [`$PIPESTATUS` array](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism#Special_Variables) contains the exit codes of each of the commands in your pipeline, in the same order as the original pipeline.